# I keep getting this error when I'm trying to open the 'update_item' page

Tags: javascript, python, django, python-requests, backend

Django Version: 3.2.5
Python Version: 3.9.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',

```
'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'store.apps.StoreConfig']
```

Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

```
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
```

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BOLARINWA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\BOLARINWA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\BOLARINWA\websites\ecommerce\store\views.py", line 36, in updateItem
    data = json.loads('request.body')
  File "C:\Users\BOLARINWA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\BOLARINWA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\BOLARINWA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

Exception Type: JSONDecodeError at /update_item/
Exception Value: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a string `'request.body'` into `json.loads` in your `store/views.py`, you need to pass actual data:

```
data = json.loads(request.body)
```